# Contact Form 7 HTTP Referred Information

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

My last question was closed before I was able to log back in to this site to add my code so I'm opening it up again and adding a bit extra.

On my wordpress site I have a number of different registered users who site end-users are able to contact. However, due to restrictions on displaying their email addresses on the front end, I have a single contact form 7 form page setup, and each registered user has an 'Email Me' button under their name.

What I'm trying to achieve on the CF7 form is:
 - add the registered users email address to the 'To' field
 - add the post title from the referred page to the 'Subject' field

If I add the contact form to the registered users profile page, I can get their email address with:

```
function cf7_get_author_email($atts){
    $value = '';

    if(get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' )) {
        $value = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' );
    }

    return $value;
 }

 add_shortcode('CF7_AUTHOR_EMAIL', 'cf7_get_author_email');
```

And also the post title as the subject with:

```
[dynamichidden pagetitle "CF7_get_post_var key='title'"]
```

But I don't want to add the contact form directly to each post/user profile page, and I need to to be centralised so that the 'Email Me' button goes to the single Contact page, but it gets the post title and the email address of which ever registered user someone is trying to contact.

I've tried:

```
function getRefererPage( $form_tag )
{
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $form_tag['title'] == 'subject' ) {
$form_tag['values'][] = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
return $form_tag;
}
if ( !is_admin() ) {
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag', 'getRefererPage' );
}
```

But this only gives me the URL in the body of the message and isn't sufficient.

I don't know jQuery, but I know $HTTP_REFFERED with jQuery is someway to go about it, but I don't know how.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: the value HTTP_REFERER can be filtered by the browser. I recommend you to put the user ID in the URL to know which user receive the e-mail.

Comment: Do you have an example as I’m lost now

Comment: you put a hidden tag with the value [with this](https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-the-context/) and then you put the correct e-mail with the filter [`wpcf7_mail_components`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/contact-form-7/tags/5.1.5/includes/mail.php#L96)

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at this

Comment: This all seems to relate to the contact form being on the same page as the author. The contact form is a separate page that the email me link directs to